# Bash script printing a variable value after a newline character

Tags: bash

I have bash script which calls another script(some_script). some_script expects some input from the user. I have used printf statement for this purpose.
But the problem is the variable value is not being accepted by the target script. I think this is because '\' is being taken as an escape character in the script

The statement somewhat looks like this

```
 printf 'yes\n$var1\n$var2\n$var3' | some_script
```

If i directly replace the variable with values it runs perfectly but i want the script to take the values from the variables. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `"` and `'`. Try

```
printf "yes\n$var1\n$var2\n$var3" | some_script
```

because with `'` the variables won't get substituted.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, `\` is a character that has to be escaped.

Use `\\n`.

For more details we would need more details on how your script works.

Comment: This is not the problem... Variable substitution is